# Multiple ports node.js application deployment on web/cloud

Tags: node.js

I have an electronic board, which collects data from sensors and I hope to send it to an web service, which then does some processing and sends the results to an website, when URL is entered. I use multiple ports for this. One port listens for UDP connection and other port is for HTTP. The code works fine on my local machine. Here is the code

```
var net = require('net')
   ,dgram = require('dgram')
   ,express = require('express')  
   ,io = require('socket.io')
   ,routes = require('./routes')
   ,http = require('http')
   ,fs = require('fs');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
var HOST = '192.168.0.132'
var PORT = 1337
var datarr = []

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('view options', {layout:false, pretty:true});
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true   })); 
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
});

//ROUTES

app.get('/',routes.index);

//UDP Server
var decoder = new (require('string_decoder').StringDecoder)('utf-8')
var buffer = '';
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

    server.on('listening',function() {
       console.log('Listening');
    });
    server.on('message', function(data,rinfo) {
            console.log(decoder.write(data));
            io.sockets.emit('data',decoder.write(data));
    });
    server.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('closed');
    });
server.bind(1337,'192.168.0.132');

//UDP server ends

var io=require('socket.io').listen(app);
app.listen(1185);

io.sockets.on('connection',function (socket) {
    console.log('Hello Got a connection');

});

console.log("server listening");
```

I know it can't be hosted on heroku, because it allows only one port.

What are my options?

1)According to some answers on this website, websockets. But i have no idea on how to set up websocket between udp and http server. Any links to websites/github would be very helful.

2)Hosting services which allow multiple ports. Are there any which provide this service? Links to documentations will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 1185;
```

and then use this port variable as

```
app.listen(port);
```

every time when you need to run on different port just use

PORT =  node app.js